# For-loop to read multiple .csv files in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, standard-deviation

I started using Python and have the following problems here.

1. Indentation Error with count +=1 and several other lines
2. Not scanning all .csv files in a directory. When I run this script, it only shows outputs of only one .csv file instead of multiple .csv file outputs on the first column. There must be an issue with for loop commands that I have.
3. I need to take the standard deviation of each line of the fileand take the mean value of standard deviation of all the lines in each file.

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python

   import os

   print "Filename, Min, Max, Average, Mean of Std"
   for file in os.listdir("."):
       if not file.endswith(".csv"):
               continue    
       csv = open(file)    
       sum = 0
       diff = 0
       std = 0
       sumstd = 0
       count = 0
       min = 0
       max = 0

       for line in csv.readlines():
           x = line.split(",")
           time  = x[0]
           value = float(x[1])
           sum  += value       
           if value > max:
               max = value

           if 0 < value < min:
               min = value 
               count += 1
           avg = sum / count   

       import math
               count +=1
               diff += (value - avg)**2
               std = math.sqrt (diff / (count+1)-1)
               sumstd += std
               meanstd = sumstd/count


   print file + "," + str(min) + "," + str(max) + "," + str(avg) +  "," + str(meanstd)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You have used `sum` as a variable name, but this will hide the built-in `sum` function. Hiding built-ins is naturally discouraged.

1. Indenting is important in Python. The line `import math` is indented only as much as `for line in csv.readlines():`, so the body of the `for` loop ends with the previous line. The recommended place for imports is at the start of the script, like you have done with `import os`.
2. You have:

   ```
   if file.endswith(".csv"):
       continue
   ```

   Therefore, it will skip and file whose name ends with ".csv". Don't you mean:

   ```
   if not file.endswith(".csv"):
       continue
   ```

   Note that this is case-sensitive.

   By the way, the recommended way of reading CSV files is with the `csv` module.

Comment: I made that change. Thank you. Do you know happen to know why I keep getting errors with count +=1 for mean of standard deviation calculations?

Answer (score 0):

Going off how SO formatted your question it looks like you may have an extra space starting at `for line in csv.readlines():`. An extra space will account for your indentation error. As for everything else, you will need to fix your formatting for us to be of any help. Python relies on whitespace, so make sure you keep it intact.